# ImportError while importing a python file in a pyd

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, pyd

Alright, so, what I'm trying to do is import a module in folders packed inside of a .pyd file. Here is something that would work for me:

```
from apple import __init__
```

With apple being the .pyd in the same directory as the Python script, and __init__ of course being packed inside of the .pyd. This would work, however here is what I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
from apple.seed.worm import WormManager
```

Explanation: apple = pyd, seed = directory in the pyd, worm = directory in seed directory in apple pyd, WormManager = python module in the worm directory.

However, it does not work, and results in a module not found ImportError thinking that seed is a module (and there was an __init__ inside of the seed directory before it was packed). Of course it exists and is packed in the .pyd, but it simply does not work. I even did this:

```
from apple.seed import __init__
```

but not even that works so I know that I'm not importing this right.

I really could not find the correct syntax for getting this to work on the internet, and of course I know how to do this without a pyd involved, so any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that Python cannot dynamically discover internal pyd API without importing it first.

You should try to import the pyd first:

```
import apple
```

Then you can (probably) access the internal API:

```
WM = apple.seed.worm.WormManager
```

Also, your `apple.pyd` dll file must contain a function `PyInit_apple()` per the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll). If it doesn't, or if it is ill-defined (doesn't define all the submodules), this may explain why you cannot do `from apple ...`.

Answer (score -2):

You need to run `C:\path\to\pip\tool\pip install pyd` from the command line first.

Comment: I just did, not exactly sure how this helps... could you elaborate a bit on how you solve the problem of importing?

Comment: Also, I don't think you get what I mean. A .pyd is the same as a .dll, but for Python, not this d language thing.