# ImportError while importing a python module in a pyd

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, import, importerror

Alright, so, what I'm trying to do is import a module in folders packed inside of a .pyd file. Here is something that would work for me:

```
from apple import __init__
```

With apple being the .pyd in the same directory as the Python script, and __init__ of course being packed inside of the .pyd. This would work, however here is what I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
from apple.seed.worm import WormManager
```

Explanation: apple = pyd, seed = directory in the pyd, worm = directory in seed directory in apple pyd, WormManager = python module in the worm directory.

However, it does not work, and results in a module not found ImportError thinking that seed is a module (and there was an __init__ inside of the seed directory before it was packed). Of course it exists and is packed in the .pyd, but it simply does not work. I even did this:

```
from apple.seed import __init__
```

but not even that works so I know that I'm not importing this right.

I really could not find the correct syntax for getting this to work on the internet, and of course I know how to do this without a pyd involved. I could really appreciate help with this because I'm really struggling and I really need this done for a job.

Note: I'm not talking about the pyd library, I'm talking about a .pyd file (like a .dll).

Comment: "directory in the pyd" What?

Comment: Let me explain further. If it wasn't packed in the pyd, the module I would want to import is apple.seed.worm.WormManager. Now that it's packed in a .pyd, I'm not sure how I import the module. "directory" was a bad word to use. As said, there are __init__.py's packed inside of the .pyd for every module, however I can't import modules inside of packed directories.

Comment: How exactly do you "pack in a pyd"?

Comment: I compiled all of the files for my program into a .pyd file. Sounds a bit crazy, but the Python modules are literally compiled into a .pyd file.

Comment: What did you use to compile them together?

Comment: I used Visual C++ 2008 tools (link.exe, cl.exe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError while importing a python file in a pyd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546652/importerror-while-importing-a-python-file-in-a-pyd)